# Composer autoloader cannot find class

Tags: laravel, autoloader, composer-php

I have an issue with the class loading of classes.

After installing my package it does not find the class, here is its error message:

```
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [SundayIT\ChatbotAdmin\Commands\DBM_RealtimeStats] does not exist.
```

Here is first few lines of the class that is missed by the autoloader:

```php
<?php
    namespace SundayIT\ChatbotAdmin\Commands;

    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

    class DBM_RealtimeStats extends Command
```

Here is the relevant part of the package's `composer.json` file

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SundayIT\\ChatbotAdmin\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

And here is the file structure:
[image: Directory screenshot]

What am I missing? I have tried checking the other questions here, but I have not found a solution. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, I did tried that and it gives the same message:`

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [SundayIT\ChatbotAdmin\Commands\DBM_RealtimeStats] does not exist.

  at C:\Users\molba\PhpstormProjects\example_chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
`

Comment: Have you tried renaming your class to `DbmRealtimeStats` and the file to `DbmRealtimeStats.php`?

Comment: Try Adding `classmap` section in composer.json > autoload section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PSR-4 standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) class names should not contain underscores.

> Underscores have no special meaning in any portion of the fully qualified class name.

That's why renaming the class to `DbmRealtimeStats` and the file to `DbmRealtimeStats.php` worked (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033250/composer-autoloader-cannot-find-class?noredirect=1#comment102477114_58033250)).